# Calculate working and non working Hrs of a device in particular day based on its ignition status

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate, working hours of forklifts on a particular day based on their ON/OFF ignition status.
My code is perfectly working fine when I ignore the condition were either ON or OFF are missing.

Requirement:
Need to handle boudary conditions were last entry of the day for a device  is ON
or you can say , if last entry off a day is ON, then we need to calculate its working hrs. till 12 PM midnight.And subsequently add working hrs. in next day as well

Dataset :

DEVICEID :  DATETIME:   IGNITIONSTATUS

1   1/11/2020 8:00  ON

1   1/11/2020 14:00 OFF

2   10/28/2020 7:54 ON

2   10/28/2020 12:23    OFF

2   10/28/2020 14:01:44 PM  ON

2   10/29/2020 20:01    ON

2   10/29/2020  14:01:44 PM OFF

1   12/10/2020 8:27 ON

1   12/10/2020  15:44:22 PM OFF

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\avyas2\Desktop\DataToTest.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"DEVICEID", Int64.Type}, {"DATETIME", type datetime}, {"IGNITIONSTATUS", type text}}),
    #"Split DateTime" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "DATETIME", (dt) => {DateTime.Date(dt), DateTime.Time(dt)}, {"Date", "Time"}),
    #"Group by Date" = Table.Group(#"Split DateTime", {"DEVICEID", "Date"}, {{
        "AvailabilityStatus",
        each
            let
                times = _[[Time], [IGNITIONSTATUS]],
                ins = List.Sort(Table.SelectRows(times, each [IGNITIONSTATUS] = "ON")[Time]),
                outs = List.Sort(Table.SelectRows(times, each [IGNITIONSTATUS] = "OFF")[Time]),
                zip = List.Select(List.Zip({ins, outs}), each _{0} <> null and _{1} <> null )
            in
                zip
        , type {{time}}
    }}),
    #"Split AvailabilityStatus" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Group by Date", "AvailabilityStatus"), "AvailabilityStatus", (x) => x, {"ON", "OFF"}),
    #"Added Worked Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split AvailabilityStatus", "Hours Worked", each Duration.TotalHours([OFF] - [ON]), type number),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Worked Time",{{"Hours Worked", "WorkingHrs"}})
    in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: What if there are multiple ON/OFF ON/OFF in a day?

Comment: @mkRabbani
Then we need to consider them all and group for a particular day to get the actual working hr

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You need only a DAX measure?

```
WorkingHour = 
var _thisLine = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet2[DATETIME] )
var result = if(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet2[IGNITIONSTATUS] )="ON",  
var minDate = CALCULATE( min(Sheet2[DATETIME]), filter(ALL(Sheet2), Sheet2[DEVICEID] = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet2[DEVICEID] ) && Sheet2[DATETIME] > _thisLine && Sheet2[IGNITIONSTATUS] ="OFF" 
&& DATE(YEAR(Sheet2[DATETIME]),MONTH(Sheet2[DATETIME]),DAY(Sheet2[DATETIME])) = DATE(YEAR(_thisLine),MONTH(_thisLine),DAY(_thisLine))
))
return
if( ISBLANK(minDate),DATE(YEAR(_thisLine),MONTH(_thisLine),DAY(_thisLine)) +1 ,minDate) - _thisLine
)

return

result
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying @msta42a
the Above solution seems fine but still , two things are missing ..
1. Can we group these two working hrs together and make one entry for the day
2. Previous day working hrs are not added in the next day  , as we receive the first entry as OFF

Comment: Also the DAX Measure you have created is for excel ?? not for PowerBI

Comment: This is a DAX measure (tested in powerbi desktop)

Comment: Also can you help in achiving this

1. Can we group these two working hrs together and make one entry for  day 2. Previous day working hrs are not added in the next day , as we receive the first entry as OFF